# Maximized Main Form follows the restore window if I open another form, and I dont want that

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I have a main form maximized in Access that I do not want to be in restore window or hidden or closed when another form opens.

I observed that when I open another form by DoCmd.Restore by clicking a button in the main form, the main form is also doing the restore window.

[image]

When I clicked a button in the main form, say Add Record, with DoCmd.Restore, my main form is doing a restore window rather than staying in maximized window

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your code? Is this a MDI form? Is there logic in the Maximize and Minimize events? An image would also help illustrate the problem.

Comment: Hi JeremyIt a plain DoCmd.Restore.  No logic in the Maximize or Minimize events

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing. If you don't want to un-maximize your forms, don't do `DoCmd.Restore`.

If you want to open another form non-maximized, but keep the main form maximized, you need to make the second form a **popup** form.

This is how MDI windows work - you can't have maximized and non-maximized forms at the same time - except popup forms.